# Preposition after abitare?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I asked someone if they lived in a certain dormitory on campus called “bob hall” by saying “Tu abiti bob hall?”. I’m wondering if it would’ve been more correct to say “Tu abiti *in* bob hall” or if they're equivalent...

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: It should be *abiti alla Bob Hall?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the transitive form of the verb *abitare* when you refer the abode of a person, his home, or his dwelling place, so if someone lived for a long time in a dormitory room, you could say "abiti la stanza 31 di bob hall". Otherwise it would be better to use the intransitive form, with the preposition *a*, for instance "abiti a bob hall?" or "abiti al bob hall?".

If you ask someone “Tu abiti bob hall?” you give the impression of asking them if they use the whole dormitory as their own home.

Comment: Secondo http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/hall/ *hall* in italiano è usato come femminile.

Comment: @egreg forse hai ragione, in italiano hall è femminile, ma penso che "Bob Hall" sia il nome proprio di un dormitorio, che in italiano è maschile. Ad esempio un ospedale che si chiama "Villa Qualcosa" rimane maschile, o no? Ci penso un attimo e poi eventualemnte correggo. Grazie comunque per la puntualizzazione.

Comment: @CasaMich I ho sempre usato il femminile in tal caso (e.g. [villa Salus](http://www.ospedalevillasalus.it/view.php?page=1495113909&sezione=1231425194&subsezione=1495113909)). Non so se ci siano regole specifiche: sarebbe un'idea fantastica per una nuova domanda!